# Mongoose fetch array field which contain specific elements

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm currently building objects in mongodb mongoose inside 1 collection.
Here's the mock data:

```
>[
>   {_id: 1, name : "parent 1", parent: null},
>   {_id:2, name = "child", parent : [1]},
>   {_id:3, name = "grandchild", parent : [1,2]},
>   {_id:4, name = "greatgrandchild 1", parent : [1,2,3]}
>   {_id:5, name = "greatgrandchild 2", parent : [1,2,3]}
>]
```

so I was trying to query out all the children of "child" base on the array of parent id,
here's the mongoose method:

Model.find({"parent" : { $elemMatch: { $in : [1,2]}}});
my expected result is :

```
[    
    {_id:3, name = "grandchild", parent : [1,2]},
    {_id:4, name = "greatgrandchild 1", parent : [1,2,3]}
    {_id:5, name = "greatgrandchild 2", parent : [1,2,3]}
]
```

instead it gave me

```
[    
    {_id:2, name = "child", parent : [1]},
    {_id:3, name = "grandchild", parent : [1,2]},
    {_id:4, name = "greatgrandchild 1", parent : [1,2,3]}
    {_id:5, name = "greatgrandchild 2", parent : [1,2,3]}
]
```

notice there's a document with id 2 included

I realized the mistake, 
the method is equivalent to

```
select * from table where parent in(1,2)
```

is there a way to fetch properly?

cheers

Comment: your asking it to find [1,2] AND that's what's it's doing

Comment: @Didi thank you for the comment.
yes, I realized the mistake, I have no idea yet on how to fetch my expected result, hope the question is understandable .

Comment: not quiet but lemme try to understand, you want to find all where parent is [1,2] and exclude name = "child" is this correct?

Comment: what I'm trying to find is all document who have 1,2 as the parent, therefor id 3,4,5 should be the output as in 1,2 is their ancestors.

Comment: if my answer solved your problem please select as the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach using $all which is similar to $and :

```
Model.find({"parent" : { $all:[1,2]}}, callbackfunction)
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Comment: child is just place holder for the name, what i need is something to fetch if the documents has 1 AND 2 as their ancestors.

Comment: you cant just say find where elements match [1,2] it will return all with [1,2] if you need other conditions, the conditions will have to be specified. its like find all shoes of size 45, 46 and expecting it return only red and blue coloured shoes.

Comment: if you notice the document with "child" as a name only have "1" as the parent.

Comment: cool, thanks. actually i found out this will work: 
Model.find({$and : [{"parent" : 1}, {"parent" : 2}]});

but your solution is better because i can send the whole array as the param of $all operator.

cheers, good day

Comment: please change your answer explanation : 
"Try this approach using notequals to child :"

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer, mongodb will trace into the sub document so normal and will work.

Model.find({$and : [{"parent" : 1}, {"parent" : 2}]});